# Remove whitespace before tabular within textblock*

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-alignment

Could you help me align Text2, within tabular and textblock*, to the baseline of Text1?

Would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock*}{30mm}(30mm,30mm)
    Text1
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{30mm}(30mm,30mm)
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
    Text2
\end{tabular}
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Struts are added in the lines of a tabular. If `\arraystretch` is not redefined, `\strut` can be added:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock*}{30mm}(30mm,30mm)
    Text1\strut
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{30mm}(30mm,30mm)
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
    Text2
\end{tabular}
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

Otherwise:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\newcommand*{\arstrut}{%
  \vrule height\arraystretch\ht\strutbox
         depth\arraystretch\dp\strutbox
         width0pt\relax
}

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock*}{30mm}(30mm,30mm)
    Text1\arstrut
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{30mm}(30mm,30mm)
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
    Text2
\end{tabular}
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Update:** Reverse the correction by moving the tabular block.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock*}{30mm}(30mm,30mm)
    Text1
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{30mm}(30mm,30mm)
\settoheight{\dimen0}{Text1}%
\kern\dimen0\relax
\kern-\arraystretch\ht\strutbox\relax
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
    Text2
\end{tabular}
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would it be possible to have normal text height in `tabular`? Your solution aligns Text1 to baseline of Text2, which is not exactly the same as aligning Text2 to baseline of Text1.

Comment: Great update!  .