# Remove extra vertical padding before tabular in textpos absolute environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, textpos, glue

I am trying to position a tabular using textpos in absolute mode. In my observation there is some extra spacing that gets added before the first row. This leads to misalignment in the the vertical position of tabular and normal text placed side-by-side using textpos. What length is it that tabular adds before the first row, and can it be set to 0pt?

Example:

```
\begin{textblock*}{\gridtextwidth\gridxscale}[0,0](5cm, 5cm)%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}lll@{}}%
            Some text & some more text & even more text\\%
            Some text & some more text & even more text\\%
            Some text & some more text & even more text\\%
            Some text & some more text & even more text\\%
    \end{tabular}%
\end{textblock*}%
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Struts are added in the lines of a tabular creating the space. Compare the position of `Text1` without `tabular` environment and `Text2` in `tabular` environment

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock*}{30mm}(30mm,30mm)
    Text1
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{30mm}(30mm,30mm)
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
    Text2
\end{tabular}
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

### To reverse the correction created by the strut

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock*}{30mm}(30mm,30mm)
    Text1
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{30mm}(30mm,30mm)
\settoheight{\dimen0}{Text1}%
\kern\dimen0\relax
\kern-\arraystretch\ht\strutbox\relax
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
    Text2
\end{tabular}
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

Please see the following explanation on this website [Remove whitespace before tabular within textblock*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70717/remove-whitespace-before-tabular-within-textblock---)  thanks to @HeikoOberdiek